# Разбить массив по элементам второго массива

Tags: php

Есть массив типа:

```
abcsbbc
adsdv
absutd
ffdbbc
ffdddv
auuutd
...
```

есть второй массив типа:

```
bbc
ddv
dv
utd
```

так вот мне нужно разбить значения первого массива по значениям второго чтоб получилось так:

```
abcs_bbc
ads_dv
abs_utd
ffd_bbc
ffd_ddv
auu_utd
```

Важно понимать что во втором массиве может быть минимум 2 буквы. Тоесть скрипт должен учитывать только те буквы которые в самом конце элементов первого массива, так как элементы второго массива всегда в конце первого.

Comment: А если не будет соответствия, что предпринимать?

Comment: Выдавать необработаный элемент первого массива

Comment: Количество элементов в двух массивах одинаково?

Comment: нет, так же нужно изящное решение, минимум строк, так как множеством проверок я и сам могу решить.

Comment: каким должен быть результат, если, например, ключи во втором массиве смещены? делать поиск по ним?

Comment: Элементы 2 массива могут быть смещены, получаеться что при анализе 1 массива нужно перебирать элементы 2 массива.

Comment: Может быть случай, когда элементы второго массива одинаковы? или когда они могут подходить под 1 элемент первого массива, если может, то что делать в таком случае?

Comment: Элементы 2 массива всегда разные. В первом массиве может быть много элементов которые содержит 2 массив. Но всегда они в самом конце элементов первого массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже сам нашел решение, вот:

```
foreach($arr1 as $x){
    foreach($arr2 as $z){
        if(preg_match("/$z$/", $x)){
            $this->array[$x][0] = preg_replace("/$z$/", '', $x);
            $this->array[$x][1] = $z;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr2 as $value) {
    foreach ($arr1 as $key => $search) {
        $arr1[$key] = preg_replace("/$value$/", "_$value", $search);
    }
}

print_r($arr1);
```